# unique opportunity <to see> <for seeing>

Tags: infinitives

Consider these sentences, please:

The exhibition is a unique [*opportunity* ***to see*** her later work].

I am [*ready* ***to go***].

are the following sentences idiomatic?

The exhibition is a unique [*opportunity* ***for seeing*** her later work].

I am [*ready* ***for going***].

In other words, can we use **for + Ving** to modify nouns and adjectives when talking about **purpose**.

Comment: No, I don't think they are. _For_ goes better with a noun - _opportunity for study of her work, ready for departure_.

Comment: Have a look at Google Ngrams for **opportunity to see,opportunity for seeing** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opportunity+to+see%2Copportunity+for+seeing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copportunity%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copportunity%20for%20seeing%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Copportunity%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Copportunity%20for%20seeing%3B%2Cc0